# How to make a column of CheckedComboBoxEdit in GridControl with different sourcedata for each row?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have problem with DevExpress XtraGrid. I wont to make a column of CheckedComboBoxEdit's, but i dont know how to make them work separately.
For example, in first row my CheckedComboBoxEdit will contain "a" and "b", and in second "b", "c", "d".

I thought i can use sth like this:

```
    List<CheckedListBoxItem> listOfCheckedItems = new List<CheckedListBoxItem>();
    listOfCheckedItems.Add( new CheckedListBoxItem( "test" ) );
    CheckedComboBoxEdit checkedCombo = new CheckedComboBoxEdit();
    gridView1.AddNewRow();
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue( gridView1.RowCount - 1, gridView1.Columns[ 1 ], checkedCombo );
```

Where: gridView1 is MainView of my gridControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ColumnView.ShownEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event and [`ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic) and [`ColumnView.FocusedColumn`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedColumntopic) and [`ColumnView.ActiveEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ActiveEditortopic) properties.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gridView1.FocusedColumn.FieldName != "YourCheckedComboBoxColumn")
        return;

    var editor = (CheckedComboBoxEdit)gridView1.ActiveEditor;
    editor.Properties.Items.Clear();

    var value = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "YourEyeColumn").ToString();

    if (value == "Eye Color")
        editor.Properties.Items.AddRange(new CheckedListBoxItem[] { new CheckedListBoxItem("Green"), new CheckedListBoxItem("Blue"), new CheckedListBoxItem("Grey") });
    else if (value == "Eye Size")
        editor.Properties.Items.AddRange(new CheckedListBoxItem[] { new CheckedListBoxItem("Big"), new CheckedListBoxItem("Medium"), new CheckedListBoxItem("Small") });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but unfortunately, its doesnt work for me. cells doesnt change after this event.
Is there any other possibilities to make it?
I just wont to make grid like this:
For example:
row 1) "Eye Color" | CheckComboBoxEdit with "Green", "Blue", "Grey"
row 2) "Eye Size"  | CheckComboBoxEdit with "Big", "Medium", "Small"
and so on.

Comment: @Fils You can use [`GridView.GetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic) method. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, it's works great for ComboBoxEdit (which i decided to use), but still i have problem to update CheckComboBoxEdit - its just dosent wont to update. With ComboBoxEdit and others controls I dont have this problem, strange. One more time: thanks for help.